# how to create symbolic link for file saved on hadoop 2.5 version

Tags: hdfs, symlink

I am a freshmen about HDFS,my question is how to create symbolic link for file saved on hadoop 2.5 version.I used java API to access hdfs to create symbolic link(symlink) and an exception as follow:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Symlinks not supported
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.createSymlink(DistributedFileSystem.java:1328)

My java code as follow：

1st, add some content in hdfs-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>test.SymlinkEnabledForTesting</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

2nd, call java API.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.create.symlink", "yes");
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", HdfsServer);
URI uri = URI.create(HdfsServer);
String target = "/tmp/target.csv";
Path targetPath = new Path(target);
String uriWithLink = "/tmp/link.csv";
Path linkPath= new Path(uriWithLink );
FileContext fc = FileContext.getFileContext(uri,conf);
fc.createSymlink(targetPath, linkPath, true);
```

Is there someone could give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Symlinks not supported

The Above exception may occur due to not enabling the symlink even you gave in hdfs-site.xml. Refer this link for more understanding [link for Reason to Exception](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.4.1/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem.java#DistributedFileSystem.createSymlink%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%2Cboolean%29)

So before FileContext, enable the symlink first.

something like this

```
FileSystem.enableSymlinks();  // See linked patch: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10020
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But there is still a problem. 1st, i modified the hdfs-site.xml in /etc/hadoop/conf,added some content in this xml file <property>
    <name>test.SymlinkEnabledForTesting</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>